# Sonata Admin nested forms

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Im using the Sonata Admin bundle for the back office of an ecommerce project.

You can create brands, add collections, items, sub items and price.
All of these elements are entities.

It seems like, with sonata admin (using the 2.3 branch) I can't add more than 2 levels of nested collections (https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/1971)

How is the best way to work around that lacking feature and still be sonata friendly?

Comment: I currently have the exact same problem, I need that in order to simplify my backend...

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the patch of https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/1971/files, it should work.

I am using it in some projects and i can add an infinite number of nested levels.

The only way that i know is copy / paste in your SonataAdminBundle the modified files.